# I need a Mysql query to preform calculation to output the following code

Tags: mysql, sql

## I have this table

#### rateID      hotelID     Rate        Date

#### 1                  1            35        2020-06-09

#### 2                  1            30        2020-06-10

#### 3                  1            40        2020-06-11

#### 4                  2            15        2020-06-09

#### 5                  2            25        2020-06-10

#### 6                  2            18        2020-06-11

## I Need the following output:

#### hotelID     Total_Rate        NumberOfNights

#### 1                105                            2

#### 1                48                              2

I need a procedure or a query that have the ability to give me this output

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your output may not be quite right. Second row `hotelID` should probably be 2, and `NumberOfNights` for both rows should be 3 probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for the output @lurker pointed out, your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT HOTELID, SUM(RATE) AS TOTAL_RATE, COUNT(DATE) AS NUMBEROFNIGHTS
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY  HOTELID
```

Output:

```
HOTELID   |  TOTAL_RATE  |  NUMBEROFNIGHTS
  1       |      105     |        3
  2       |      58      |        3
```